# Not able to pass variable to function in Python

Tags: python, function

```
def describe_pet(animal_type='hamster', pet_name):
 """displays information about a pet"""
     print("\nI have a " + animal_type+ ".")
     print("My " +animal_type +"'s name is "+pet_name.title()+".")
describe_pet(animal_type='hamster', pet_name='harry')
```

I am not able to run the following code in Python. I was able to run this code in a linux machine but it is not working on a windows 10 machine. I am using python 3.7

When i run the code i get the following error message. Please advise if there is a problem OS or python version as i am not sure what version of python was installed on the linux machine!

```
 """Display information about a pet."""
                                         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your docstring (`"""displays information about a pet"""`) needs to be indented as if it were part of the function (indent it with 4 spaces)

Comment: **IndentationError: expected an indented block** Best and clearest error message I've ever seen

Comment: even if i get rid of the docstring i still get the following error: 
    def describe_pet(animal_type='hamster', pet_name):
                    ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Comment: Also a very clear message. You have to list all non-default arguments before any arguments with default values.

Comment: To explain further, when calling a function, arguments such as `animal_type='hamster'` are called "keyword arguments", whereas arguments like `pet_name` are called "positional arguments". In python, you must always declare positional arguments *before* keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks @ResetACK for your explanation. That fixed my problem!

Comment: "Even if i get rid of the docstring i still get the following error:" - yes; that's a **different problem** that motivates a **separate question** (which would also be a common duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

As said above and in the exception, the indentation is wrong.
I've also seen that you use 5 spaces as indentation.
That could bring you some more trouble in the future.

I'd suggest you to use some ide that checks your code for such errors like [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) or [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with pydev.
As a bonus you will take advices how to write [good styled code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```py
def describe_pet(animal_type='hamster', pet_name):
    """displays information about a pet"""
    print("\nI have a " + animal_type+ ".")
    print("My " +animal_type +"'s name is "+pet_name.title()+".")

describe_pet(animal_type='hamster', pet_name='harry')
```